# How can I plot individual data points in a map using R/ leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, ggmap, r-leaflet

I am trying to show the individual points in a given place, like a map equivalent of dot plot. I tried with `leaflet` library in R, but I am only able to map the size of the marker to the continuous variable. Is it possible to map the individual data points as clusters instead of mapping the size of the marker to the continuous variable?

My data looks like this

```
Lat,Lon,Place,People
19.877263,75.3390241,Aurangabad,1
20.2602939,85.8394548,Bhubaneshwar,2
30.7194022,76.7646552,Chandigarh,23
13.0801721,80.2838331,Chennai,25
11.0018115,76.9628425,Coimbatore,2
27.4844597,94.9019447,Dibrugarh,1
16.2915189,80.4541588,Guntur,1
17.3887859,78.4610647,Hyderabad,4
22.5677459,88.3476023,Kolkata,7
15.8309251,78.0425373,Kurnool,1
9.9256493,78.1228866,Madurai,1
```

Comment: What do you mean by cluster? Can you show what is your expected output?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following code to have dot plot

```
leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat, 
             popup = ~Place)
```

[image]

## Data

```
df = structure(list(Lat = c(19.877263, 20.2602939, 30.7194022, 13.0801721, 
11.0018115, 27.4844597, 16.2915189, 17.3887859, 22.5677459, 15.8309251, 
9.9256493), Lon = c(75.3390241, 85.8394548, 76.7646552, 80.2838331, 
76.9628425, 94.9019447, 80.4541588, 78.4610647, 88.3476023, 78.0425373, 
78.1228866), Place = structure(1:11, .Label = c("Aurangabad", 
"Bhubaneshwar", "Chandigarh", "Chennai", "Coimbatore", "Dibrugarh", 
"Guntur", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata", "Kurnool", "Madurai"), class = "factor"), 
    People = c(1L, 2L, 23L, 25L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: I did this..then mapped radius of the circle marker to the people..what I am trying is to replace the marker at say, Chennai, with 25 small dots.. is it possible? couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`leaflet` works great with `sf` package. Taking a sample of your data points

```r
lat <- c(19.877263, 20.2602939)
lon <- c(75.3390241, 85.8394548)
place <- c("Aurangabad", "Bhubaneshwar")
```

You can convert them in spatial object using `sf` package. For `leaflet` to give you tiles, you need to have WSG84 coordinates. I assumed your data were in this coordinate system.

```r
library(sf)

df <- data.frame(lon, lat, place, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
points <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
```

Then it's easy to plot with `leaflet`. Assuming you want markers that popup the name of the place when you click

```r
library(leaflet)
leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(popup = ~ place)
```

[image]